# Vert.x Web and session fixation

Tags: java, vert.x, session-fixation

Using Vert.x Web handlers is it possible to fix session fixation problems (ie change the session id after user is authenticated), or do I have to implement my own session handling? I need a session during login handling, and I don't see how to create a new session with authentication tokens (or change the session id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertx session id is regenerated when an upgrade from unauthenticated to authenticated happens.

You can request a new I'd atbany time with the method: `Session.regenerateId()`